# erlang for loop for queries

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have this function:

```
show_employee_table() ->
    do(qlc:q([B || B <- mnesia:table(employee)])).
```

What it does is that it goes to a table called employee and prints the contents to the user.

Concept: I want to make another function say called `show(times) -->`, this function will take a table name and the number of times to call the show_table function.

If I input (employee,100), I want to have a for loop that runs 100 times, the idea is to measure the time taken to run the loop. In java I would do something like this:

```
Time t = time.now();
for ( I=0; I<N; I++){
show_employee_table() ->
    do(qlc:q([B || B <- mnesia:table(employee)])).
}

Time t2 = time.now();

timetaken = t2 - t1;
```

That's how I want to do it, but in erlang. I just don't know the syntax in erlang and I would appreciate it if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For time measurement, use: [timer:tc/1, timer:tc/2, timer:tc/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1). So we will have a recursive function called `loop` which may be doing anything you want. Then we would measure the time it takes to loop by applying

```
{TimeTaken,Result} = timer:tc(?MODULE,loop,Args).
```

`Args` must be a list of arguments to the function say, a table and a number, like this

```
measureLoopTime()->
   Args = [employee,100],
   {TimeTaken,_Result} = timer:tc(?MODULE,loop,Args),
   TimeTaken.

loop(_,0) -> done;
loop(Table,Number)->
  %%% do something ....
  loop(Table, Number - 1).
```

That's the correct erlang implementation of your java code. Follow the link to the timing function to see in which units the time is returned.

Comment: ok thank you Muzaaya , I will write you in my acknowledgement section when all this is done, u helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Erlang doesn't have loops like java. Instead you would be using recursion.
Eg:

```
show_employee_table(0) -> done;
show_employee_table(Times) ->
    do(qlc:q([B || B <- mnesia:table(employee)])),
    show_employee_table(Times - 1)
.
```

You would cont down for each step, and when you reach 0 you are done..

If you do this alot you could make a function for it:

```
times(_, 0) -> done;
times(Call, Times) ->
   Call(),
   times(Call, Times - 1)
.
```

Call it like this:

```
   times(fun () ->  show_employee_table() end, N).
```

Comment: I will try to implement the times one and give u feedback, thank you for the response

Comment: I tried to implement this function and i dont get the output, this is how i wrote it:

**
%% for the loop
times(_, 0) -> done;
times(Call, Times) ->
   Call(),
   times(Call, Times - 1).
   
%% calling it
looping(N) ->
times(fun () ->  show_employee_table() end, N).
  ** 
project:start().
ok
6> project:write_tables().
{atomic,ok}
7> project:show_employee_table().
[{employee,7,"Lana ",1,female,99143},
 {employee,5,"Antonio ",2,male,99514}]
8> project:looping(5).
done

I was expecting to see the output of the show_employees_table(), 5 times, can you help?